# Boolean Expression / Regexp in NodeJS

Tags: regex, node.js, boolean

I have a problem in Node.JS and I am not sure if it is maybe some weird language feature, a bug or if I am plain overworked so pls. don't judge. I have already shown this to two more ppl, though.

```
    var testa = (req.direction == zCore.get('DIRECTION.Incoming')),
        testb = burnerRE.test(req.text),
        testc = yuilopRE.test(req.text),
        testd = viberRE.test(req.text),
        teste = whatsappRE.test(req.text),
        testf = kakaotalkRE.test(req.text),
        testg = generalCodeRE.test(req.text)
    ;

    // THIS IS TRUE
    console.log(testa);

    // ONE OF THESE WILL BE TRUE
    console.log(testb);
    console.log(testc);
    console.log(testd);
    console.log(testd);
    console.log(teste);
    console.log(testf);
    console.log(testg);


    // THIS IS SOME HOW FALSE
    console.log(testa && (testb || testc || testd || teste || testf || testg));
```

Comment: There isn't really enough information here to diagnose the problem, as what you've shown looks fine.  Is this exactly the code that's failing?  Can you post a complete script that behaves differently from what you expect?

Comment: You should include the exact values of testa-g for when the result is false.